# Import issue with IronPython and Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, python, .net, ironpython

I want to integrate IronPython in my .NET C# Library but I have always the following exception

> Additional information: No module named *'modulename'*

In my C# library project, I've installed the following IronPython NuGet

> Install-Package IronPython
>
> Install-Package IronPython.StdLib

**Python simple code (getLogScaledPNG.py):**

```
import numpy as np    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def getLogScaledPNG(filename):      
        data = plt.imread(filename);    
        data[data == 0.] = np.nan;      
        logdata = np.log(data);         
        plt.imsave("logimage.png", logdata, cmap="gray");
        print 'Scaled Image Saved'
```

**C# code:**

```
using IronPython.Hosting;

var ipy = Python.CreateRuntime();

dynamic getLogScaledPNG = ipy.UseFile(@".\PythonScripts\getLogScaledPNG.py");
getLogScaledPNG.getLogScaledPNG("toto.png");
```

When I execute this C# code, I've got the following Exception:

> Additional information: No module named numpy

I don't understand where and how can I add this module ?
I just have the reference to the IronPython DLLs in my .NET project and I haven't got any folders where I can add this module

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the IronPython DLLs, you need Python standard library scripts.

[Download IronPython.StdLib.2.7.8.zip](https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython2/releases/tag/ipy-2.7.8), extract everything to a folder

And add this to your code:

```
ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();

var searchPaths = engine.GetSearchPaths();
searchPaths.Add(@"C:\yourLibFolder");

engine.SetSearchPaths(searchPaths);
```